# Inserting an image with class using :before

Tags: css

I am inserting an image into a div container with css like this:

```
.ft-folder-closed:before {
    content: url('../ll-filetree/img/ft-plus.16.png');
}
```

I want apply some css attributes to that image without listing them in the together with the "content" attribute, but apply a nother style to it, to reduce CSS overhead. Something like this, but that of course does not work:

```
.ft-folder-closed:before {
    content: url('../ll-filetree/img/ft-plus.16.png');
    inherit: ft-floder-icon;
}
```

Any chance to do that?

Comment: The only way I know to do that is using a CSS pre-processor like LESS or SASS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group your CSS selectors to apply the same styles on multiple elements.  This allows you to apply the same styles to multiple elements without repeating the styles.

Example:

```
.ft-folder-icon, .ft-folder-closed:before {
     color: red;
}
```

This will apply the color: red; style to both the .ft-folder-icon elements and the .ft-folder-closed:before pseudo-elements.

If you decided to use a CSS pre-processor like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) you could abstract your CSS using "mixins" similar to this:

```
.ft-folder-closed:before{
     .ft-folder-icon;
}
```

Using "mixins" you can embed all of the properties of a class into another class just by including the class name as one of its properties.  It's very similar to variables, but for entire classes.